# how to schedule a script created in VScode (WSL) - Python

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a script that I want to schedule to run each lets say every 10min.
this script downloads a csv file in this folder.
C:\Users\rsharma\scripts\cylance\external_devices

Script name is external_devices.py and I have created it in visual studio code (WSL).
now I know I can use Crontab and windows scheduler to schedule it but nothing seems to be working.

this is my script path
C:\Users\rsharma\scripts\cylance\External_devices.py

these are the crontab entries I have tried
*/10 * * * *  /mnt/c/Users/rsharma/scripts/cylance/External_devices.py
*/10 * * * *  /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/c/Users/rsharma/scripts/cylance/External_devices.py

windows scheduler entries -
program - C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe
argument - /mnt/c/Users/rsharma/scripts/cylance/External_devices.py

Comment: You shouldn't be using WSL crontab. This question assumes you are using Windows and VScode but you haven't made that clear in the OP. The WSL crontab will not be guaranteed to be running in the Hyper-V lxss system process so all automated windows jobs should be  defined in the Windows Scheduler. Probably best to re-write the question as to how to run a Python script in the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: Hi Rob, 
I am pretty new in the prog. field so sorry for the confusion.
I don't have python installed on my windows machine its on WSL.
I will rephrase my question but any help in the solution. I doubt about the path I am giving for the script in the windows scheduler is right ?

Answer (score 2):

Please move the script out of "/mnt/c/Users...." directory and copy to another directory in the C drive. The WSL mount point is only available when the lxss Hyper-V WSL is started so will not be mounted unless VSCode is running. It's now much better to use the WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.4) version which you can download from the Microsoft store and then install into as an extension "VSCode Remote Extensions for WSL" which will mount into "/home/username" and is much much faster and feature rich, especially if you plan to use Docker as it is directly integrated.

Install Windows Python into a directory of your choice for example - c:\Python. You will obviously need to install any libraries that the Unix version uses. There will be a binary

```
c:\Python\Python3.x\python.exe
```

That will need to be coded into a batch windows command file (xxx.cmd). To run your script change to the directory the script is saved and run the python command.

Example code for xxx.cmd batch file:

```
cd c:\scriptdirectory
c:\Python\Python3.x\python.exe External_devices.py
```

Run this on the command line to ensure it works, then schedule in the Windows Scheduler as appropriate.

Comment: thanks mate, this hasn't solved my problem yet but I think you've defined exactly what I was doing wrong. great answer, legend!